# Execute read operations in sequence - Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to execute below operations in sequence as given:-

```
 PCollection<String> read = p.apply("Read Lines",TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile())) 

      .apply("Get fileName",ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,String>(){
          ValueProvider<String> fileReceived = options.getfilename();
          @ProcessElement
          public void procesElement(ProcessContext c)
          {
              fileName = fileReceived.get().toString();
              LOG.info("File: "+fileName);
          }
      }));

      PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read from BigQuery",
              BigQueryIO.read()
                  .fromQuery("SELECT table,schema FROM `DatasetID.TableID` WHERE file='" + fileName +"'")
              .usingStandardSql());
```

How to accomplish this in Apache Beam/Dataflow?

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case? It seems like these are simple read operations without any side effects, so I don't see why it would matter whether they are executed sequentially or in parallel, or how an external observer would even be able to detect which of these is the case.

Comment: Okay...as you might've noticed, I'm using the variable value in "fileName" derived in the operation "Get fileName" in the following query to read from a BigQuery table.
But what's happening is the "Read from BigQuery" operation is happening before "get fileName" and hence it gets a null value. Therefore it is imperative that the operations happen sequentially.

I guess the above is happening because I'm using p.apply again while reading from BigQuery...how to tackle this situation?

Comment: Ohh, I see, I missed that part. Before I address this - I'm confused by something else in your code. Your DoFn always outputs the same value, coming from your PipelineOptions, and ignores the contents of its input PCollection (i.e. the result of your TextIO.read() is effectively thrown away). Is this intentional?

Comment: Yeah...i mean i did that only to access the value of the filaName...the result of TextIO.read() is used later in the program...so it's not thrown away as such...

Comment: As written in the code snippet, it is thrown away - I presume your actual program is different then. Additionally, in this snippet you are outputting the value of options.getfilename() not once, but N copies of it where N is the number of lines in all files matching the pattern "getInputFile()" - i.e. the PCollection "read" contains this many identical copies of options.getfilename(). I think I can suggest how to do what you are actually trying to do; will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to apply `BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery()` to a query that depends on a value available via a property of type `ValueProvider<String>` in your `PipelineOptions`, and the provider is not accessible at pipeline construction time - i.e. you are invoking your job via a template.

In that case, the proper solution is to use `NestedValueProvider`:

```
PCollection<TableRow> tableRows = p.apply(BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery(
    NestedValueProvider.of(
      options.getfilename(),
      new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String filename) {
          return "SELECT table,schema FROM `DatasetID.TableID` WHERE file='" + fileName +"'";
        }
      })));
```

Comment: I just have another question related to it if you don't mind...is there a way to directly insert the data from the file read in "Read lines" into BigQuery using the schema and table retrieved from the above function.
I tried referring to DynamicDestinations in Apache Beam and a post that you suggested  - stackoverflow.com/a/43505535/278042 but couldn't figure out how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind posting a separate question for that, including more details of what exactly you tried and what isn't working? That way, more people will be able to see it and learn from the answer.

Comment: Sure @jkff...!!